# PostgreSQL backup in custom format ( -F c) fails during pg_restore ( copy command in log )

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, pg-restore

We have a PostgreSQL custom format ( -F c ) database backup ~1Gb in size that could not be restored on two of our users machines.
The error that occurs is

> :pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData and in logs there is error in Copy command.

All reports we found with errors in Copy command during pg_restore were related to textual (sql ) backup which is not the case.

*Any ideas?*

Below is the information that describe the issue in more details:

**1.**  File integrity is ok checked with ["Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)

**2.**  Backup and restore and restore are performed with  PostgreSQL 9.6.5  64 bit.

**3.** Backup format of pg_dump is called

```
pg_dump -U username -F c -Z 9  mydatabase >  myarchive
```

**4.** Database on client is created with:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase  WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8'  OWNER=user;
```

**5.** Pg_resote  call:

```
pg_restore.exe  -U user --dbname=mydatabase   --verbose --no-owner --role=user
```

**6.** Example of logs, there are repeating rows with random table errors:

```
2020-12-07 13:40:56 GMT LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (21 seconds apart)
2020-12-07 13:40:56 GMT HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-12-07 13:40:57 GMT ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
2020-12-07 13:40:57 GMT CONTEXT:  COPY substance, line 21511: "21743    \N  2   1d8c29d2d4dc17ccec4a29710c2f190a    e98906e08d4cf1ac23bc4a5a26f83e73    1d8c29d2d4dc17ccec4a297..."
2020-12-07 13:40:57 GMT STATEMENT:  COPY substance (id, text_id, storehouse_id, i_tb_id, i_twod_tb_id, tb_id, twod_tb_id, o_smiles, i_smiles_id, i_twod_smiles_id, smiles_id, twod_smiles_id, substance_type)
2020-12-07 13:40:57 GMT FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 48
2020-12-07 13:40:57 GMT LOG:  PID 105976 in cancel request did not match any process
```

or

```
2020-12-07 14:35:42 GMT LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (16 seconds apart)
2020-12-07 14:35:42 GMT HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-12-07 14:35:59 GMT LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (17 seconds apart)
2020-12-07 14:35:59 GMT HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-12-07 14:36:09 GMT ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
2020-12-07 14:36:09 GMT CONTEXT:  COPY scalar_calculation, line 3859209
2020-12-07 14:36:09 GMT STATEMENT:  COPY scalar_calculation (calculator_id, smiles_id, mean_value, remark) FROM stdin;
2020-12-07 14:36:09 GMT FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 49
2020-12-07 14:36:10 GMT LOG:  PID 109816 in cancel request did not match any process
```

Comment: Please, upgrade to the latest minor release. Does the same happen with a plain format dump?

Comment: plain sql dump would explode in size and it  is not an options since database is distributed with app installation

Comment: I am not suggesting that you use a plain format dump, I am asking to narrow down the problem. If the plain format dump fails too, then it is easier for you to find the line in the `COPY` data that fails and add it to the question, along with the table definition.

Comment: We assume that the problem is not in the file backup because it restores wo problem on hundrets other boxes including our ~30 developer and testing machines. The machines that problem have arised are not available for testing we just can ask for logs , configurations and so on.

Comment: Well, then you won't be able to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar behavior on windows 10 pro machines with PG 11.x.

I used pg_dump as suggested above and restored to said machines with psql and had no error.

I also noted that the error shifted around using pg_restore with different "-j" settings.  For instance without the setting or "-j 1" pg_restore always fails on the same table and record.  Changing to "-j 4" results in that table succeeding to apply the record without error but it occurs on another table.

Changing a particular column to null in the record satisfies the entire restore.

Using pgAdmin 4 to run the restore never produces the error.
Copying the exact command displayed in pgAdmin reproduces the same error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 32780; 0 5435293 TABLE DATA REDACTED_TABLE_NAME postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "REDACTED_TABLE_NAME": ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY mi_gmrfutil, line 117: "REDACTED PLAIN TEXT  \N  REDACTED PLAIN TEXT \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  REDACTED PLAIN TEXT \N  \N  REDACTED PLAIN TEXT \N  ..."
pg_restore: FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 49
```

I tried using pg_restore version 14 with the same outcome.

Comment: Am understand it correct if restore throught pgadmin 4 restore dialog the same archive that has been failed  with pg_restore is restored without errors